# I need my Macros "Save" button to add a new row every time new data is saved, not replace the current one that was saved before

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I just need for my Macro to save the information and add a new row to another sheet within the same workbook without replacing the old saved data but instead add a new row.

I am very new at this and I need expert help, thank you to everyone who is willing to help.

```
    enter code here

function CopyandPaste() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('J3:N3').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Work Log Data'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:E3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Customer Interface\'!J3:N3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

I need for all of the data copied from range `J3:N3` to be copied into Sheet "Customer interface" without replacing the information copied before, by adding a new row every time the "save" button is clicked. Thanks!!

Comment: Look at  [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) appendRow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.  But it's hard to tell.  Macros may be easy to make but they make poorly documented scripts.

```
function CopyandPaste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('J3:N3').activate();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Work Log Data'), true);
  ss.getRange('A3:E3').activate();
  ss.getRange('\'Customer Interface\'!J3:N3').copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Customer Interface');
  var rg=sh.getRange('J3:N3');
  var values=rg.getValues();
  sh.appendRow(values[0]);
}
```

Version Edited by OP:

```
function CopyandPaste() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  ss.getRange('J3:N3').activate(); 
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Work Log Data'), true); 
  ss.getRange('A3:E3').activate(); 
  ss.getRange('\'Customer Interface\'!J3:N3').copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); 
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Work Log Data'); 
  var rg=sh.getRange('A3:E3'); 
  var values=rg.getValues(); 
  sh.appendRow(values[0]); 
}
```

In answer to your question in the comments:

```
function CopyandPaste() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  ss.getRange('J3:N3').activate(); 
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Work Log Data'), true);
  ss.getRange('A3:E3').activate(); 

  //this copies from 'Customer Interface'!J3:N3 to 'Work Log Data'!A3:E3
  ss.getRange('\'Customer Interface\'!J3:N3').copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);


  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Work Log Data'); 
  var rg=sh.getRange('A3:E3'); 
  var values=rg.getValues(); 
  //this append 'Work Log Data'!A3:E3 to the bottom of the 'Work Log Data'
  sh.appendRow(values[0]);
}
```

Comment: function CopyandPaste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('J3:N3').activate();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Work Log Data'), true);
  ss.getRange('A3:E3').activate();
  ss.getRange('\'Customer Interface\'!J3:N3').copyTo(ss.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Work Log Data');
  var rg=sh.getRange('A3:E3');
  var values=rg.getValues();
  sh.appendRow(values[0]);
}

Thanks to your code I was able to edit it a little and make it work perfectly!!! THANK YOU SOOOOOOOO MUCH. This made my week!!

Comment: Glad you able to make use of my suggestion.

Comment: One more question though, for some reason when I press the "Save" Button and the task runs, I get 2 rows of the same value. How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you share your execution log?